# Java code to generate JSON hierarchical path

Tags: java, json, parsing, jsonpath

I am working on a project where I need to parse a JSON in Java and display the hierarchical path of a JSON key/node as mentioned below.

I'm developing this program in Java using Jackson API but I am not able to get any readily available API which will return me hierarchical path of a current key/node from JSON.

**JSON Data** -

```
{“tomcat-users”:
    {
        “role”:[
            {“@rolename”:”manager-gui”},
            {“@rolename”:”manager-script”},
            {“@rolename”:”manager-jmx”},
            {“@rolename”:”manager-status”}
        ],
        ”user”:{
            “@username”:”admin”,
            ”@roles”:”manager-gui,manager-script”,
            ”@password”:”admin”
        }
    }
}
```

**Output should be like** -

```
Column 1                                        Column 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
tomcat-users -> role[1] -> @rolename            manager-gui
tomcat-users -> role[2] -> @rolename            manager-script
tomcat-users -> role[3] -> @rolename            manager-jmx
tomcat-users -> role[4] -> @rolename            manager-status
tomcat-users -> user -> @username               admin
tomcat-users -> user -> @roles                  manager-gui,manager-script
tomcat-users -> user -> @password               admin
```

Can anybody please tell me, is their any API available which will return me the path ?

**My Java Code -**

```
public static void generateJsonPath(JsonNode node) {
     Iterator<String> fieldNames = node.getFieldNames();
     while(fieldNames.hasNext()){
         String fieldName = fieldNames.next();
         JsonNode fieldValue = node.get(fieldName);
         if (fieldValue.isObject()) {
            System.out.println(fieldName + " -> ");
            generateJsonPath(fieldValue);
         } else if(fieldValue.isArray()) {
             System.out.println(fieldName + " -> ");
             Iterator<?> iterator = fieldValue.getElements();
             while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                 generateJsonPath((JsonNode) iterator.next());
             }
         } else {
            String value = fieldValue.asText();
            System.out.println(fieldName + " : " + value);
         }
     }
}
```

**Java Code Result -**

```
tomcat-users -> 
role -> 
@rolename : manager-gui
@rolename : manager-script
@rolename : manager-jmx
@rolename : manager-status
user -> 
@username : root
@password : root
@roles : manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status
```

Comment: You could parse JSON into a POJO and then display the values in the POJO in the above mentioned format.

Comment: Thanks R.J. I am doing this in my REST service but the JSON structure is not fixed. Currently I am converting JSON into JsonNode (see the code as mentioned above).